# IF statement not running in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a code to declare a variable and then an IF statement which uses that variable to either display, or not display an image.

This code is before HTML

```
<?php $contents = file("textdocument.txt") ?>
```

This code is in the HTML

```
<?php if ( $contents = 10 ) { 
echo '<img src="image.png" name="image" border="0">'; }
else {echo "wrong number"; } ?>
```

The problem I get is no matter what the number is, the image always displays. Do you guys have any solutions for this?

Comment: And the number that changes is the text of the textdocument.txt, not the $contents = 10

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<?php if ( $contents = 10 ) {
```

should be

```
<?php if ( $contents == 10 ) {
```

Don't worry, it's a common mistake :)

Comment: I recommend reversing these checks so it doesn't happen and it throws an error -- use `if ( 10 == $contents ) {` instead, and there will never be any chance of accidentally assigning the value to the variable.

Comment: I tried this however now it just says "wrong number". Am I making another mistake?

Comment: alter `file(..)` to `trim(file_get_contents(..))`

Comment: building on that:

`if (intval(file_get_contents(..)) === 10) {`

Comment: Rather than reversing the check as suggest by Nathan Loding, get into the habit of paying closer attention when using comparison operators. You will usually **not** be comparing to a literal but rather variable to variable, i.e., `($a == $b)` where reversing helps nothing.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a single `=`, you are performing an *assignment* on that variable. And that expression ends up being the value you stored to the variable. So, `if ($contents = 10)` is basically the same as `if (10)` (which is always "true" in PHP)

You need to use a [comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), such as `==` to compare the value of `$contents` with the value you are looking for. (ie. 10)

Also, the function [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) returns an array, with each value of that array corresponding to 1 line of the file. So, you either need to use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to return everything as a single string, or reference the particular line of that file as the index of the array.

```
// Using file()
$contents = file("textdocument.txt");
if ($contents[0] == 10) {
    // If the contents of the first line of the file is '10', do something
}

// Using file_get_contents()
$contents = file_get_contents("textdocument.txt");
if ($contents == 10) {
    // If the contents of the entire file is '10', do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, your "=" should be replaced with "==".

A good habit to get into to avoid this type of mistake in the future is to swap the order of the comparison, as in:

```
if(10 == $contents)
```

This way, if you mistakenly use the assignment operator in place of the comparison, it will result in an error, rather than a tough-to-spot bug:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='
```